# how to call .aex file in after effects script?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, script

i want to apply a transition between two video clips and the transition is a .aex file. i can apply ffx with "applyPreset".

how can i apply it via script? or even an outside code?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got an answer in adobe forum:

just add the aex effect as a string and AE will do the rest..

> var myLayer = app.project.activeItem.layer(1);
>   myLayer.property("Effects").addProperty("Linear Wipe");